# How to set a do...while loop on a switch statement and add inputs?

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm currently working on a project that must take a integer 1-10 switch it to a double then multiple that double with a quantity. However, all of these have to be input by the user like you're ordering something from a restaurant. The problem I'm having is getting a loop of the above that stores the total (price * quantity) and then adds it all up. exp: 1 * 5 = 5 + 4.5 * 2 = 9 = total of 14. I have to loop this to a point where the user can terminate the loop with an input. I've tried doing this by adding a counter++ to the switch as a case but nothing I do seems to work. Below is the current code I'm working on.

So all in all, I need below to loop (until prompted not to) and continuously add up the totals until I get one final total at the `System.out.println("total");` line

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package Menu;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author -------
 */


public class Menu {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    double price = 0;
    int ItemNum;
    int quantity;
    double change;
    double total;
    double payment;
    int counter = 1;


    System.out.println("Welcome to Home Italliano!\nHit enter for menu.");
    keyboard.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Menu" +"\n"+"(1)Noodles - 1.15$"+"\n"+"(2)Pizza Slice - 3.00$"
        +"\n"+"(3)Lasagna - 4.99$"+"\n"+"(4)Beverage - 2.25"+"\n"+"(5)Md. Pizza - 7.85$"+"\n"+
        "(6)Lg. Pizza - 11.10$"+"\n"+"(7)Calzone - 3.30$"+"\n"+"(8)Garlic Knot - 1.25$"
        +"\n"+"(9)Rg. Pasta - 8.00$"+"\n"+"(10)Triple Meat Pasta - 9.99$");

    while (counter ==1)
    System.out.println("Please input the number of the item you wish to order. hit 0 for total.");
    ItemNum = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the quantity for this item");
    quantity = input.nextInt();

    total = price * quantity;

    switch (ItemNum){
        case 0:
            counter++;
        case 1:
            price = 1.15;
            break;
        case 2:
            price = 3.00;
            break;
        case 3:
            price = 4.99;
            break;
        case 4:
            price = 2.25;
            break;
        case 5:
            price = 7.85;
            break;
        case 6:
            price = 11.10;
            break;
        case 7:
            price = 3.30;
            break;
        case 8:
            price = 1.25;
        case 9:
            price = 8.00;
            break;
        case 10:
            price = 9.99;
            break;
        default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a menu item.");

    } 

    System.out.println(total);


        }

            }
```

Comment: Put an open bracket `{` after your `while(counter==1)` line and a close bracket `}` after the switch statement.

Comment: I can't see how the code above gets past the "Please input the number..." line as it is at the moment: it looks like it will keep printing that statement indefinately.

Comment: Your while loop doesn't have brackets so the next line is the only line in the loop and it never exists the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- Enclose your logic in an infinite loop (i.e. `while(true))`.
- Mind your curly brackets for the loop
- Either use a specific `int` or use `Scanner.nextLine` to get a `String` representation of the input (i.e. "q" for "quit"), and `break` the infinite loop if matched (you will need some `String`->`int` conversion in this case)
- It's "Italiano", with one "l"

Comment: I changed up the entire coding to start the while(true) before the menu and threw in an if break; seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop doesnt have any braces:

```
while (counter ==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

as other have pointed out: Your while loop is missing the braces and thus only affects the second line.

Also: You are accessing the price before you have determined it through your switch clause.

While it might work if you add the braces, your solution should look more like this:

1, Create a private class for the Items on the Menu. Such a MenuItem would have a name and a price.

2, Then create a java.utils.HashMap of MenuItems. Then you init this map with your Menu. 
A Map maps a given Key (in this case the menuNumber) to a given Object (in our case a MenuItem Object)

E.g.:

```
menuMap.put(1, new MenuItem("Noodles", Double.valueOf("1.15"));
```

3, Do the Initial Output;

```
System.out.println("Menu:");
for(String key: menuMap.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(menuMap.get(key).toString());
}
```

4, Create a while loop, like such

```
//Initially Scan for and validate ItemChoice
while(!inputMenuNumber == 'Exit Signal')
{
    //Scan for and validate Input Amount

    MenuItem chosenItem = menuMap.get(inputMenuNumber);
    total = chosenItem.getItemPrice() * Integer.valueOf(inputAmount);

    //Scan for and validate ItemChoice
}
Sytem.out.println(total);
```

It makes the code a lot easier to read and to comprehend.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I added the braces to the while loop and after the switch. but now I get System.out.println(total); throwing an error on total as the variable might not be intializing.